# Qt Installer Framework: Auto Update

Tags: qt, auto-update, qt-installer

I'm currently using the Qt Installer Framework and managed to set up an online repository. What I want to know is:

Does the Framework provide some kind of "auto-update" mechanism, e.g. a plugin/service that checks for updates every time the program/system starts?
Check for updates would be enough, since the installation itself can be done using the maintanance tool.

All I could find about this topic was this small sentence:

> End users can use the maintenance tool to install additional components from the server after the initial installation, as well as to **receive automatic updates** to content as soon as the updates are published on the server.

from here: http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-overview.html#choosing-installer-type

Thanks for your help!

**Edit:** Suggestion
Based on this question's accepted answere I created a small library to automatically check for updates using the installer framework - https://github.com/Skycoder42/QtAutoUpdater

Comment: You may find [Mendeley/Update-Installer](https://github.com/Mendeley/Update-Installer) interesting.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What I do, is run the maintenance tool using QProcess, and then check the output. It has a mode where it doesn't run the GUI but only outputs update information if available.

Note that I set the working directory to the application's path when the applications starts, so I can just run maintenancetool.

```
QProcess process;
process.start("maintenancetool --checkupdates");

// Wait until the update tool is finished
process.waitForFinished();

if(process.error() != QProcess::UnknownError)
{
    qDebug() << "Error checking for updates";
    return false;
}

// Read the output
QByteArray data = process.readAllStandardOutput();

// No output means no updates available
// Note that the exit code will also be 1, but we don't use that
// Also note that we should parse the output instead of just checking if it is empty if we want specific update info
if(data.isEmpty())
{
    qDebug() << "No updates available";
    return false;
}

// Call the maintenance tool binary
// Note: we start it detached because this application need to close for the update
QStringList args("--updater");
bool success = QProcess::startDetached("maintenancetool", args);

// Close the application
qApp->closeAllWindows();
```

Comment: Is this put in controller.qs or isntallscript.qs?

Comment: @Franco you add this C++ code to your application source code.

Answer (score 4):

In the latest Qt Installer Framework 4.1 `--checkupdates` returns nothing, use `ch` or `check-updates` instead.

```
Commands:
  in, install - install default or selected packages - <pkg ...>
  ch, check-updates - show available updates information on maintenance tool
  up, update - update all or selected packages - <pkg ...>
  rm, remove - uninstall packages and their child components - <pkg ...>
  li, list - list currently installed packages - <regexp>
  se, search - search available packages - <regexp>
  co, create-offline - create offline installer from selected packages - <pkg ...>
  pr, purge - uninstall all packages and remove entire program directory
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found a pretty nice implementation on GitHub:

https://github.com/ioriayane/TheArtOfQt2/blob/master/src/HelloWorld/maintenancetool.cpp

It takes care of handling Windows, MacOS and Linux. + It is written to use in QML / Qt Quick bindings (+ example).

It has some Japanese comments, but is Apache 2.0 licensed, so freely to use (following Apache 2.0 requirement).

Answer (score 0):

There's a section in the guide about how to do it, but they call it promoting updates rather than auto updates, [IFW Updates on doc.qt.io](http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-updates.html).

Comment: I saw that one, but if I understand right, the user will have to run the MaintananceTool to get those updates?

Answer (score 0):

Based on answers here, I made a it for PyQt apps. Instead of checking if the maintenancetool output is empty or not it actually parses it:

```
from AnyQt.QtCore import QProcess
from AnyQt.QtWidgets import QApplication
from AnyQt.QtXml import QDomDocument

def extract_xml(self, data):
    xml_string = str(data, encoding='utf-8')
            
    # Find the start and end positions of the XML content
    start_pos = xml_string.find('<?xml')
    end_pos = xml_string.find('</updates>') + len('</updates>')
    xml_content = xml_string[start_pos:end_pos]
            
    return xml_content

def parse_xml(self, xml_content):
    doc = QDomDocument()
    doc.setContent(xml_content)
            
    # Access and process the XML data as needed
    root = doc.documentElement()
    updates = root.elementsByTagName('update')
            
    package_names = []

    for i in range(updates.count()):
        update = updates.item(i)
        if update.isElement():
            element = update.toElement()
            name = element.attribute('name')
            version = element.attribute('version')
            # size = element.attribute('size')
            # _id = element.attribute('id')
            package_names.append( (name, version) )

    return package_names

# ...

updates_list = []
updater_tool_path = "maintenancetool.exe"
if updater_tool_path:
    process = QProcess()
    params = ["ch"]
    process.start(updater_tool_path, params)
    process.waitForFinished()

    if process.error() != QProcess.UnknownError:
        print("Error checking for updates")
        # Handle error

    data = process.readAllStandardOutput()
    xml_content = extract_xml(data)
    updates_list = parse_xml(xml_content)
 else:
     print("Couldn't found maintenancetool.exe for checking updates")
     # Handle error

# If there are updates let's start maintenancetool with "Update components" radiobutton selected:
if len(updates_list) > 0:
    args = ["--updater"]
    success = QProcess.startDetached(update_tool_path, args)
```